# Accounting for ghosts in calculation of massless closed string emission

Tags: string-theory, ghosts

I've been trying to do problem 5.8 from String Theory in a Nutshell by Kiritsis, which is think, also related to problem 8.10 in Polchinski. My question is this: how do we account for ghosts in the case of a single vertex? I could be saying something really stupid here, but if I fix the vertex operator at one position, then I can have $c$ and $\tilde{c}$ associated with that position, but to get a non-zero amplitude, I need a minimum of three ghost insertions. So where does the third ghost insertion go?

This question was also posed in [Graviton Emission from D-Branes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/graviton-emission-from-d-branes), but the ghost problem wasn't answered. Any help would be appreciated. TIA!